# Function that searches for a specific node in a Binary Tree?

Tags: c, binary-tree

I'm trying to write a function that traverses a tree until it finds a node that contains a given value (in this case a symbol). I tried something like this:

```
struct HuffTreeNode* findNode (struct HuffTreeNode* root, unsigned char symbol)
{
  if (root != NULL)
  {
    if (root->symbol == symbol)
    {
      return root;
    }
    else
    {
    findNode(root->left,symbol);
    findNode(root->right,symbol);
    }
  }
  return root;
}
```

So if I called `findNode(root,'c')`, it would return the node that contains "c". 
However, I can't seem to get the above function to work, any ideas?

Note: I know that the above function doesn't have a response if a node with that given symbol doesn't exist, but for now I'm just calling it using symbols that I know are contained within the tree.

Comment: `findNode(root,"c")`. Are you really invoking it like that? The second arg is incorrect. It should be `'c'`.

Comment: What does *"I can't seem to get the above function to work"* mean? Also you recursively call `findNode` on the right and left, but you don't do anything with their return values.

Comment: And you are not actually returning any results from your recursive invocations.

Comment: 1. passing pointer converted from array  `"c"` to the `unsigned char` argument is nonsense. 2. I think you should return`NULL` instead of `root` for not-found. 3. Use `if` statement to avoid traversing more and return the node found when found.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: I know that the above function doesn't have a response if a node with that given symbol doesn't exist,

That's the first problem. You return `root`, even if it's not the right node. You should return `NULL` in this case.

Next, you recursively call `findNode` on the right and left, but you don't do anything with their return values, so your code can never work. Check the return value. If it's not NULL, that means a match was found in that sub-tree, so return it.

```
struct HuffTreeNode* findNode (struct HuffTreeNode* root, unsigned char symbol)
{
  if (root != NULL)
  {
    if (root->symbol == symbol)
    {
      return root;
    }
    else
    {
        struct HuffTreeNode *n;

        // Try the left sub-tree
        n = findNode(root->left,symbol);
        if (n)
            return n;

        // Try the right sub-tree
        n = findNode(root->right,symbol);
        if (n)
            return n;
    }
  }

  // Not found
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. A pretty silly mistake on my part. I'm still a bit iffy on recursion, so this definitely helps.

Comment: @Tyler The best thing you can do is step through your code with a debugger. Or, add debug prints.